# Custom tag g.each conflicts each closure

Tags: grails

I have a custom tag because I want to wrap g:each

```
def myEach = { attrs, body ->
    out << "${g.each(in:attrs.in, var:attrs.var, status:attrs.status) { 'test' }}"
}
```

But the each tag gets error because it is confused with the closure each.  Any way I can do this?  Worst case is I will output a gsp page that contains the each tag.

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: I expect it to behave like g:each

Comment: I just want to decorate g:each

Comment: It would help to know exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely register your own tag the same way Grails does:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovySyntaxTag;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException;

public class Whatever extends GroovySyntaxTag {

    public static final String TAG_NAME = "youreach";

    public void doStartTag() {
        String in = attributes.get(ATTRIBUTE_IN);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(in)) {
            throw new GrailsTagException("Tag [" + TAG_NAME + "] missing required attribute [" + ATTRIBUTE_IN + "]", parser.getPageName(), parser.getCurrentOutputLineNumber());
        }

        doEachMethod(in);
    }

    public void doEndTag() {
        endEachMethod();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return TAG_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isKeepPrecedingWhiteSpace() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAllowPrecedingContent() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in `Bootstrap.groovy`, register this class as a tag.

```
    GrailsTagRegistry.instance.registerTag(Whatever.TAG_NAME, Whatever.class)
```

You can create your own class that extends `GroovySyntaxTag` to manipulate any methods there. Then have this class extend that instead.

Comment: Can I use my own namespace? Instead of g, use another?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that I'm missing something, but single quotes didn't help, example:

```
def myEach = { attrs, body ->
    out << "${g.'each'(in:attrs.in, var:attrs.var, status:attrs.status) { 'test' }}"
}
```

With that you will get the same error...

My solution is to use `groovyPagesTemplateEngine` bean. With that you can parse a String template:

```
def myEach = { attrs, body ->
    attrs.content = "test"
    String template = "<g:each in='${attrs.in}'>${attrs.content}</g:each>" 
    groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(template, 'mytemplate').make([attrs:attrs]).writeTo(out)
}
```

Comment: I will try this.  What if I want the content to be the body?  Where the body can use the var and status?

Comment: I tried to add the parameter var.  But it is null inside the body of the null.
E.g. <g:myEach in="${list}" var="item">${item.name}</g:myEach>

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** If you want to call standard tag, just try to call it, like:

```
  //ApplicationTagLib g

  def myEach = { attrs, body ->
    out << g.each([in:attrs.in, var:attrs.var, status:attrs.status]) {
      'test'
    }
  }
```

---

**OLD**

If you want to put a string into output, try to use standard String, not GroovyString. Not `"${g.each....}"`, but `'${g.each....}'`:

```
out << '${g.each(in:attrs.in, var:attrs.var, status:attrs.status) { \'test\' }}'
```

Or just escape `$`:

```
out << "\${g.each(in:attrs.in, var:attrs.var, status:attrs.status) { 'test' }}"
```

Comment: I think that the first will print g.each in the view and not parse the tag.

Comment: Sure. As I understand it's what JavaDev wants. Or I missed something?

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit unclear.  I want to create my own g:each so I want the g:each behavior. the 'test' is just a sample content that will be rendered for each instance in the list.

Comment: Right.  But instead it calls each closure.  As in ['a','b'].each {}

Comment: Try to call it as usual method, w/o wrapping with string. See my update to the answer.